# Termination character reference

Tags: c, escaping

where I can find a COMPLETE termination character reference for C?
I only know %i, %d, %u... And I'm not even sure those are called "termination character": that's why I don't know how to google them.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You mean "Format specifiers". Try [here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/printf/).

Answer (score 3):

You mean printf conversion specifiers?

I would rely on the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/printf.html), since it is normative (well, normative for POSIX anyway) and free.

Comment: Also note that the parts which are extensions beyond the requirements of the ISO C standard are shaded with the `CX` marker. (C eXtension)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how complete it is, but I like this one because it's concise (which might not be what you're looking for):

- http://www.pixelbeat.org/programming/gcc/format_specs.html

Note that it also includes non-standard items (like the apostrophe flag to indicate grouping digits).